# Java Label not showing image(open cv)

Tags: java, opencv

I am making a simple red color detector program using open cv but there is a problem with my JLabel it is not showing up the threshold image below is my code.

```
while(true)
{       
    try
    {
        cap.read(mat);// object of VideoCapture class
        BufferedImage img= getImage(mat);// converts Mat to bufferedImage
        lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));// this works fine
        Mat hsv = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);// converts to hsv

        Mat thresh = new Mat() ;

        Core.inRange(hsv, new Scalar(0,100,100), new Scalar(10,255,255),thresh);

        lbl2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage(thresh)));// not showing up this
    } catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

Could anyone please tell what the issue is and how to solve it.Thanks.

Comment: You should consider printing your exception trace. This might give you information on your problem: e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @HenryMaathuis Sorry i understood what you said

Comment: Does Mat thresh = new Mat() ; return an image ?